# iOS - Make Button Subview Immune To Super View's Double Tap Recognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

In one of my app's `UIViewControllers`, I have a double tap `UIGestureRecognizer` where when the user double taps the screen, the app will start, pause, or resume the process of flashing words on the screen for a user to speed read an article. I also have a button that allows the user to go back one sentence, but the user can only do it when the user double taps to pause the reader.

However, if the user taps the button to go back one sentence twice very fast, the double tap is recognized and the app executes the blinking of words again.

I have the following code in my `viewDidLoad`:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
[doubleTapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[doubleTapRecognizer setDelaysTouchesEnded:NO];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapRecognizer];
```

Is there any way to make this button immune to the double tap `UIGestureRecognizer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

doubleTapRecognizer.delegate = self;

Return NO from gestureRecognizerShouldBegin: in case button is tapped.

Comment: Oh gosh I can't believe I had this brain lapse. Of course I should've used the delegate! I found a better method `shouldReceiveRouch:(UITouch*)touch` instead to say if `[touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]` then return NO. Thanks a ton for reminding me! :)